# How to count multidimensional json object

Tags: c#

I created the Valera class and initialized the variables from the class using the init method. The initial data was taken from the json object. Then I created the Actions class. Here I have to create methods that the Valera class can use. I have to take the data to change from another JSON object. How can I make this code work for example?

```
valera.Mana = actions.goToWork.mana; // it's not working
```

class Valera

```
public class Valera
{
    public int Health {get; set;}
    public int Mana {get; set;}
    
    public int Money { get; set;}
    public int Happiness {get; set;}
    public int Fatigue {get; set;} 
    public bool Dead {get; set;}

    public void init()
    {
        var jsonObject =
            File.ReadAllText(
                @"C:\Users\User\RiderProjects\MarginalValera\MarginalValera\Properties\characteristics.json");
        Valera obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Valera>(jsonObject);

        Health = obj.Health;
        Mana = obj.Mana;
        Money = obj.Money;
        Happiness = obj.Happiness;
        Fatigue = obj.Fatigue;
        Dead = obj.Dead;
    }
}
```

class Actions

```
public class Actions
    {
        public void goToWork(Valera valera)
        {
            var jsonObject =
                File.ReadAllText(
                    @"C:\Users\User\RiderProjects\MarginalValera\MarginalValera\Properties\actions.json");
            Actions actions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Actions>(jsonObject);
            if (valera.Mana < 50 && valera.Fatigue < 10)
            {
                valera.Mana = actions.goToWork.mana; // it's not working
            }
        }
    }
```

actions.json

```
{
  "goToWork": {
    "mana": -30,
    "happiness": -5,
    "fatigue": 70,
    "money": 100
  },
  "seeNature": {
    "happiness": 1,
    "mana": -10,
    "fatigue": 10
  },
.....
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is not working? Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they? Also, could you post the definition of the properties in the `Actions` class to which you are deserializing your data to?

Comment: The Actions class has sent everything as it is. The error is that he does not understand what actions.goToWork(or seeNature) is. So I would like to ask how can I get data from each action goToWork or seeNature and others

Comment: When you call this method `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Actions>(jsonObject)`, it tries to deserialize the `jsonObject` object to type `Actions`. In your `Actions` class, you have to have the proper structure for deserialization, otherwise it will fail to deserialize the JSON. It's hard to help without seeing the whole code, would be nice if you could include full version of your code.

Comment: I added all the code (only added in the Valera class). There are no variables in the Actions class, but I would not like to use them, adding the same variables as in Valera would be redundant. How can you act in such a situation? The Actions class is needed only to change the fields of the Valera class depending on the actions in actions.json

Comment: If your `Actions` class does not have any properties, then the deserialization of the JSON fails. It has no properties to deserialize to. You can try to use `dynamic` instead of `Actions` as type, but that isn't recommended, it's better to declare your JSON models as classes 1:1.

Comment: Don't use a person's name to name a class. Instead of the `Valera` class, create `User` or `Player` class.

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not understand how to implement my idea

Comment: To me it feels a bit confusing - why do "Actions" and some character would share the same properties without having some shared logic? It really causes confusion. My suggestion is to have a class to inherit the shared properties (mana, happiness, fatigue, money). This way the Desirialization will work. If this doesnt make sense to you - you can use `JObject.Parse` function to have a JObject. from there you can just access the 'mana' property as a json